# Cocoapod xcode workspace - swift and objective-c source files

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

First time in trying to create a cocoapod project.
I used 'pod library create name' command creating the standard template, using the swift language option.

I have added in C-files to the workspace but I don't know how to add a bridging header file so swift can import the C functions.

An attempt resulted in the compiler complaining about using a bridging header in a framework.
Is it actually possible to mix and match swift & (obj-)C files in the same cocoapod workspace/project?

[image: Workspace hierarchy]

TIA
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Woke up next morning and found the answer.
Sorry for the traffic.
Edit the XXX-umbrella.h file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).